# What is the ratio of matrices which have full rank to total number of matrices over a finite field.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

We know that
\begin{align*}
\frac{|GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|}{|\mathcal{M}_N(\mathbb{F}_q)|} &= \frac{\prod \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (q^n - q^k)}{q^{n^2}} \\
&= \prod_{k=1}^n \left( 1-q^{-k} \right) \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{q}, \frac{1}{q} \right)_n,
\end{align*}
where the last expression denotes the [q-Pockhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol).

How can we generalize this to $m\times n$ matrices. I mean what is the ratio of matrices which have full rank to total number of matrices.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a much simpler question here: "How can I count the number of full rank matrices?". Have you tried to do this? You can WLOG assume $n > m$ and work it out.

Answer (score 2):

For an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $m$ (where $m \le n$), there are $q^n-1$ possibilities for the first row, then $q^n - q^1$ for the second, etc., or
$\prod_{j=0}^{m-1} (q^n - q^j)$ in all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be too hard to write down the numerator and denominator, because the matrices with full rank will have $n$ linearly independent columns, so the first column can be any nonzero vector, there are $q^2$ linear combinations of the first two columns, etc... and that gives $(q^m-1)q^m-q)\dots(q^m-q^{n-1})$.

Meanwhile the denominator is just $q^{mn}$.

Comment: Depending on what the first and second column are, there may not be $q^{2}$ linear combinations of the first two columns (for example, the first column may be zero, or the second column could be a multiple of the first); you also don't seem to count the possibilities for the second column?

Comment: Actually, the product that you give makes very little sense. Does the second power go down by 2 each time? What happens if $n > m$?

Comment: Oh, that should have been a $q$.  Typo.  @MorganRodgers  Might you have figured that out?  The first column can't be zero.  That's the reason for the $-1$!

Comment: @MorganRodgers I thought we were counting full rank matrices.

Comment: Full row rank? Full column rank? I suppose it is not clear. It makes no difference in the count though, just the reasoning. If we just mean rank is $\mathrm{max}(m,n)$ then it could have a zero column (as long as there are more columns than rows); that is what I meant to say.

Comment: Ok.  I see your point. @MorganRodgers  And thanks for the input.  What I did will work, I think, if $m\ge n$.  Heck, we would get zero, otherwise.  So there's some ambiguity.